# Enviar informações sem finalizar o formulário (submit)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Eu possuo um formulário em html e preciso que ao preencher os campos e clicar no botão "Próximo" ele envie o formulário pelo e-mail sem que a pessoa perceba, pois o formulário continua nos próximos passos...

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="texto nomeform1" minlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo*">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input id="texto" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Válido*">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="Telefone">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sobre" placeholder="Como ficou sabendo sobre festas?">
 </div>
                            
<button type="button" name="usrSubmit" class="next action-button enviar_email" id="proximo" disabled value="Próximo"> Próximo</button>
```

Atualmente eu já consigo enviar para o e-mail as informações que eu quero porém ele finaliza o formulário...

Comment: Você quer dizer que a página atualiza e, portanto, o resto do formulário nunca é apresentado?

Comment: @JoãoLucas como o formulário é preenchido em 4 partes pelo usuário, eu preciso que na transição do passo 1 para o passo 2 seja disparado por e-mail os dados preenchido do passo 1 sem que o usuário perceba que foi enviado já uma parte dos dados dele. Atualmente ele faz o dispara o e-mail e finaliza o formulário e volta para o passo 1 para ser preenchido novamente.

Comment: O que você deve fazer é usar `Jquery` para fazer essa alternação do formulário, por exemplo, abrindo e fechando as partes de acordo com o preenchimento e depois enviar tudo de uma vez.

Comment: Mas está faltando as demais partes do formulário para se ensaiar uma resposta.

Comment: O que vem depois de enviar os dados?

Comment: Os dados devem ser enviados por e-mail, após cada passo? Ou podem ser escondidos, enquanto o passo posterior é preenchido?

Answer (score 0):

Olá @Jvs Corrêa,

Vamos partir do princípio que vc já esteja com Ajax implementado, se não estiver precisará adicionar um código como esse:

```
$("#form1 .next").click(function(){


    var form = $(this);
        var formdata = false;
        if (window.FormData){
            formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
        }

        var formAction = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url         : "form-folder/salvar.php",
            data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
            cache       : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            type        : 'GET',            
            success     : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

                // Callback code

                //alert(data);

                //$(".temp_message").html(data);


            }
        });

        return false

});//end click
```

Dessa forma, quando clicar no btn '.next', ocorrerá o envio dos dados via GET com Ajax para o arquivo que vc gerencia os dados, os enviando por email. Nesse cenário, a cada next, um novo email será enviado, sem recarregar a página.

- Se vc deseja que o email seja enviado somente no final de todos os next's, ou seja preenche o passo1, clica em next, passo2 > next e quando chega no último aí então ocorre o envio, então alguns itens a mais precisam ser implementados. Pode ser com a propria dinamica do layout, criando um mecanismo de guias, onde executa um hide() e show() de acordo com o next, ou trabalhando com sessões.